# Can't find attire_accessor in Module

Tags: ruby

On the one hand [Module#attr_accessor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor).
On the other hand:

```
Module.instance_methods.include? :attr_accessor
=> false
```

So where is **#attr_accessor** method actually defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Misunderstand you question. The method itself defined as private:

```
Module.private_instance_methods.include? :attr_accessor
=> true
```